# Error compiling and linking my shared library in C / NASM

Tags: c, linux, nasm, glibc

I am currently recoding a shared library in C and NASM similar to GLIBC for Linux x64.

I've noticed that when we compile an executable with the `-nostdlib` flag we have to add a C wrapper ourselves (example: `asm(".global _start; _start: call main; movq %rax, %rdi; movq $60, %rax; syscall");`), so I conclude that it's the GLIBC that takes care of loading `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`.

So I recoded a wrapper for `exit(int status)` in NASM, a "`main()`" wrapper. But I get a lot of warnings / LD errors.

Here are the codes:

vlibc-wrapper.h

```c
#ifdef __linux__
    #ifdef __x86_64__
        #ifndef write
            #define write(fd, buf, count) extern int _write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
        #endif

        #ifndef exit
            #define exit(status) extern void _exit(int status);
        #endif

        #ifndef blk
            #define brk(addr) extern int _brk(void *addr);
        #endif
    #endif
#endif
```

exit.asm

```
bits 64

section .text
    global _exit:function
    _exit:
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

main.asm

```
bits 64

section .text
    global _start
    extern main
    extern _exit

_start:
    call main wrt ..plt
    mov rdi, rax
    call _exit wrt ..plt
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
ASM_DIR       = ./src/ASM
C_DIR         = ./src/C
TEST_DIR      = ./test
BUILD_DIR     = ./build
TMP_DIR       = ./.tmp
INCLUDE_DIR   = ./include

ASM_FILES     = $(wildcard $(ASM_DIR)/*.asm)
C_FILES       = $(wildcard $(C_DIR)/*.c)
TEST_FILES    = $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/*.c)

ASM_OBJECTS   = $(patsubst $(ASM_DIR)/%.asm,$(TMP_DIR)/%.o,$(ASM_FILES))
C_OBJECTS     = $(patsubst $(C_DIR)/%.c,$(TMP_DIR)/%.o,$(C_FILES))
TEST_OBJECTS  = $(patsubst $(TEST_DIR)/%.c,$(TMP_DIR)/%.o,$(TEST_FILES))

LIBRARY       = $(BUILD_DIR)/libvlibc.so
TEST_EXECUTABLE = $(BUILD_DIR)/test

NASM          = nasm
NASM_FLAGS    = -f elf64

CC            = gcc
CFLAGS        = -m64 -fPIC -pedantic -fno-builtin -nostdlib -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ggdb3 -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)

LD            = ld
LDFLAGS       = -shared -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)

all: $(LIBRARY) $(TEST_EXECUTABLE)

$(LIBRARY): $(ASM_OBJECTS) $(C_OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(TMP_DIR)/%.o: $(ASM_DIR)/%.asm
    $(NASM) $(NASM_FLAGS) $< -o $@

$(TMP_DIR)/%.o: $(C_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TEST_EXECUTABLE): $(TEST_OBJECTS) $(LIBRARY)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -L$(BUILD_DIR) -lvlibc

re: fclean all

clean:
    rm -f $(TMP_DIR)/*.o

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(LIBRARY) $(TEST_EXECUTABLE)

test: $(TEST_EXECUTABLE)
    ./$(TEST_EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: all clean fclean re test
```

Tree

```bash
.
├── build
│   └── libvlibc.so
├── include
│   ├── vlibc-def.h
│   ├── vlibc.h
│   └── vlibc-wrapper.h
├── Makefile
├── src
│   ├── ASM
│   │   ├── brk.asm
│   │   ├── exit.asm
│   │   ├── main.asm
│   │   └── write.asm
│   └── C
└── test
```

Here are the warnings:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: type and size of dynamic symbol "_start" are not defined
/usr/bin/ld: warning: input symbol _start not found; no initialization of start address
/usr/bin/ld: build/libvlibc.so: undefined reference to "main
collect2: error: ld returned output status 1
make: *** [Makefile:40: build/test] Error 1
```

I suppose the warning about the absence of a `main()` function is normal, but is it possible to fix this? Since technically the `main()` function will be detected after linkage.

So I'm trying to solve all these problems so that I can code my shared library cleanly.
Can you help me ?

Comment: `#ifndef blk ... #define brk` seems wrong.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/14990641/1216776